# How can I substract 15 min from a start-time?

Tags: php

I tried to substract 15 min. from another time (start-time).
I want to check if the current time is 15 min. befor a meeting starts.

```
foreach($result->value as & $value) { 
    $start = $value->Start->DateTime; 
    $startmeeting = substr($start, 11, -11); //cut time to hour:minute

    $now= date('H:i', time());

    $min= strtotime('-15 minutes'); 
    $timebefor = date($startmeeting, $min); //Here I want to substract starttime with 15 min

    if( $now >= $timebefor && $now <= $startmeeting )
    {
        //Show yellow warning box
    }
}
```

Is it even possible on this way?

Comment: What is the value of `$value->Start->DateTime` and What is the value of `$startmeeting` at the position where you want to subtract 15 minutes?

Comment: @Jerodev $start is 2019-08-08T12:00:00.0000000 and $startmeeting is 12:00

Comment: is it a DateTime Object ?

Comment: @Frankich Timestamp :)

Comment: no i meant about `$value->Start->DateTime`, is it the object or for some reason it's only a string ?

Comment: @Frankich Yes this is the object which I got from outlook api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically have your solution, but it is untidy, and contains bugs. I think you want to do something like this:

```
foreach ($result->value as $value) { 
    $meetingStart = strtotime($value->Start->DateTime);
    if (($meetingStart > time()) && 
        ($meetingStart < strtotime('15 minutes'))) 
    {
        //Show yellow warning box
    }
}
```

Simply put: If the meeting is in the future, but less than 15 minutes into the future, you will have to show the yellow warning box.

When programming always pay attention to the names you choose. Notice how I use `$nowPlus15Minutes` which does clearly indicate what that variable contains. You used `$min` which isn't very self explanatory. The same problem exists with names like `$value` and `$start`. Perhaps `$timebefor` is a misspelling?

Comment: I will pay more attantion with the next names - thanks :) I tried it with your code and the yellow box displays all the time?

Comment: @qpA Well, I did forget about old meetings, perhaps that's the problem? I'll add that.

Comment: @qpA Try again, please. The problem for me is that I have no real way to test this code...

Comment: You dont have any real code to test, right. But your solution works perfect! Thank you :)

Comment: @qpA I refactored it a bit. I think it is still understandable this way.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you use PHP:DateTime with this. If your system works with external API (such as Google Calendar), I will usually specify the timezone too.

```
$currentTime = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone("Asia/Singapore"));
$reminderTime = new DateTime("2019-08-08T12:00:00.0000000", new DateTimeZone("Asia/Singapore"));
$reminderTime->sub(new DateInterval("PT15M")); // PT means period time, 15 minutes.

// Comparison of DateTime is allowed from PHP 5.2.2 onwards
if($currentTime > $reminderTime) {
  // Do something
}

 // For DEBUGGING
 echo $currentTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n" . $reminderTime->format('Y-m-d 
 H:i:s');
```

Refer to [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) documentation for more information.